# How do I change the yticks on pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two boxplots on a pyplot and I want to change the yticks from '1' and '2' to two stings 'Post Index' and 'Pre Index'.  How would this be done?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pre_data = [1,1,3,2,2,2,3,1,1,1]
post_data = [1,1,2,3,1]
data = [pre_data, post_data]

pre_mean = np.mean(pre_data)
post_mean = np.mean(post_data)

plt.boxplot(data,0,'',0)
plt.xlabel('Duration in Seconds')
plt.title('Example Plot')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the [`yticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels) of the current axes ([`gca()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gca) gets the current axes)

```
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['Post Index', 'Pre Index'])
```

[image]